# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints When trying to load xib file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, autolayout, ios9.3

I am trying to implement the UITableView using xib file
But when I run the app I am getting the following error & the xib is properly in small screen like iPhone4s
it works fine in larger display size.

[Screenshot of xib](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzyy3BQ5zuwfbi00Y2J1cFc0NG8/view?usp=sharing)

Any help will be appreciated

**Error**

```
    2016-12-14 17:12:41.826 FoodStrock[5776:1761262] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc2a6dfac0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fcc2a6e1010(63)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc2a617530 V:[UIImageView:0x7fcc2a6e1010]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcc2a6e1270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc2a6cc3b0 V:|-(9)-[UIImageView:0x7fcc2a6e1010]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcc2a6e1270 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc2a4955a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcc2a6e1270(59.6667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc2a6dfac0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fcc2a6e1010(63)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-12-14 17:12:41.827 FoodStrock[5776:1761262] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc2a6a69d0 V:[UILabel:0x7fcc2a6e1670'Address'(63)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc2a693820 UILabel:0x7fcc2a6e1670'Address'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcc2a6e1270.bottomMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc2a6e0c00 UILabel:0x7fcc2a6e1670'Address'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcc2a6e1270.topMargin + 1>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcc2a4955a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fcc2a6e1270(59.6667)]>"
)
```

Comment: Check your constraints properly. The error is occurring due to extra constraints. Check each constraint and remove unnecessary constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your UIImageView , UILabel, UIButton in single UIView(says mainView). Now mainView constraints will be leading, trailing, top bottom from the xib view(superView). Now constraints of UIImageView , UILabel, UIButton is according to your requirement w.r.t. mainView.

**NOTE:** Give constraints to the UIComponents as minimal as possible but keep mind about it full fills your requirement. Like here, give constraints like this:

1. UIImage : top, bottom , Leading wrt mainView and constant width or you can give horizontally center to container, leading, height, width.
2. UIButton : top, bottom, trailing wrt mainView and constant width or you can give horizontally center to container, leading, height, width.
3. UILabel : leading trailing and horizontally centre to container is enough but you can give height also.
   UILabel can automatically take height and width according to the text font size you just need to specify x and y coordinates.

Comment: Thanks Tinu for the help but I can't find UIView in the xib file

Comment: Dude you have to add new UIView, right bottom of your storyboard, drag and drop it. And then put all your components in it then work with it.